# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding IList in an Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I am attempting to bind a list that is part of a larger view model without resorting to a custom model binder. When I use an editor template to build the list of inputs, the generated names are not in the correct format for the default binder to work.

Instead of Items[3].Id like I would expect it is Items.[3].Id. If I build the list without an editor template it works as expected.

Am I doing something obviously wrong or is this just a quirk of Html.Hidden and Html.TextBox?

```
public class ItemWrapper
{
  [UIHint("ItemList")]
  public IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Index.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <h2>Index</h2>

  <% using(Html.BeginForm()) 
  {%> 
    <%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items) %>
  <%}%>
</asp:Content>
```

ItemList.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<Mvc2Test.Models.Item>>" %>

<h4>Asset Class Allocation</h4>
<% if(Model.Count > 0) { %>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
    {%>
      <tr>
        <td><%: Model[i].Name%></td>
        <td>
          <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id) %>
          <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Value) %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <%}%>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%
}%>
```

Output

```
<tr>
  <td>Item 4</td>
  <td>
    <input id="Items__3__Id" name="Items.[3].Id" type="hidden" value="f52a1f57-fca8-4bc5-a746-ee0cef4e05c2" />
    <input id="Items__3__Value" name="Items.[3].Value" type="text" value="40" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Edit** (Action Method)

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
  return View(
    new ItemWrapper
    {
      Items = new List<Item>
      {
        { new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 1", Value = 10 } },
        { new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 2", Value = 20 } },
        { new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 3", Value = 30 } },
        { new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Item 4", Value = 40 } }
      }
    });
}
```

**Edit #2**

HttpPost Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(ItemWrapper w)
{
    if(w.Items == null)
        Response.Write("Items was null");
    else
        Response.Write("Items found " + w.Items.Count.ToString());
    return null;
}
```

Index.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h4>Does Not Work</h4>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home")) 
{%> 
        <%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items) %>
        <input type="submit" value-"Go" />
<%}%>

<h4>Does Work</h4>
        <% using(Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home")) 
        {%> 
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <% for(int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++) 
            {%>
            <tr>
                <td><%: Model.Items[i].Name%></td>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items[i].Id) %>
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Value) %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
             <input type="submit" value-"Go" />
        <%}%>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have understood your problem, and i might very well have a solution too :)!

First, let me explain you what i have learned by inspecting the [framework's source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) (it's always a good idea to inspect an opensource project's source code to better understand how certain things work).

**1-)** When using **simple strongly typed** html helpers (i.e. all **Html.xxxFor(...)** methods except **EditorFor** and **DisplayFor**), in the lambda expression defining the model's property to render, the name of the html element generated is equals to whatever string follows "**model=>**", minus what comes before "**=>**", that is to say:

- the string "**model**" if the model is a **collection**
- or the string "**model.**" (note the "**.**" at the end) otherwise.

So, for example this :

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor( m=>m.OneProperty.OneNestedProperty)%>
```

will generate this html output:

```
<input type="text" name="OneProperty.OneNestedProperty" ../>
```

And this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor( m=>m[0].OneProperty.OneNestedProperty)%>
```

will generate this:

```
<input type="text" name="[0].OneProperty.OneNestedProperty" ../>
```

***==>This partly explains why you've got this "strange" html output when using EditorFor.***

**2-)** When using **complex strongly typed** helpers (EditorFor and DisplayFor), the same previous rule is applied inside the associated partial view (**ItemList.ascx** in your case), and **in addition**, all generated html elements will be **prefixed** by what comes after "==>", as explained in **1-)**.

The prefix here is "**Items.**", because you have this in your typed view (Index.aspx):

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items) %>
```

***==>This completely explains the output, and why default binder doesn't work anymore with your list of Items***

The solution will be to **break down** your **ItemWrapper** parameter in the **[HttpPost] method**, into his properties, and then use the **Bind Attribute** with his **Prefix** parameter for each complex property, like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Index(string foo,[Bind(Prefix = "Items.")]IList<Item> items)
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

*(supposing that ItemWrapper also has a simple property named **Foo** of type string)*

To avoid conflict,when listing the properties in the post method, i strongly recommend you to name your parameters according to each property's name (no mather the case) like i did.

Hope this will help!

Comment: So it's really a quirk in the way MVC generates the field names. The partial view is not taking into consideration that the model is a collection when generating the field name. I guess if the Items. is created at the view level instead of the partial view level then there may not be a good way to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: kondotine: sounds like a asp.net mvc bug, has anyone yet reported it?

Comment: Ok, reported myself: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7711, please vote for this bug fix!

Comment: I found that it is not required to breakdown the entire view model. It is enough to just separate these problematic collections into parameters, so the code may look like `public string Index(ItemWrapper wrapper,[Bind(Prefix = "Items.")]IList<Item> items)`. Tested in MVC 4

Answer (score -1):

A more lazy solution is just to use jQuery in order to "fix" instances of this sort.
Just run the following function after the page (or partial page) loads:

```
function makeHiddenInputBindable() {
    $('input[type="hidden"]').each(
        function (i) {
            $(this).attr('name', function () {
                return this.name.replace(/\.\[/g, "[");
            })
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: jQuery shouldn't be used as a crutch to rework broken HTML. Fix it on the server side.